# Set the text position to be permanent on all platforms

Tags: html

I don't know if its possible but lets say I have a paragraph in HTML and its adjusted to my screen, but when I open my file in another computer the text goes off the screen. Is there a way to set the position to be permanent on all computers?

HTML Examples:

```
<strong1 style="top: 180px; left: 40px;">I can't believe i actually did this, wow i really need to find</strong1>
<strong1 style="top: 180px; left: 523px;">what to do in my life</strong1>
```

Comment: <strong1> is not a html tag. The HTML TAG for paragraphs is <P>

Answer (score 1):

Using percentage allows you to position your elements dynamically, based on the screen size.

```
<strong1 style="margin-top: 20%; margin-left: 10%;">Some text</strong1>
```

Comment: for some reason the margin-top doesnt work, only the margin-left actually moves it..

Answer (score 0):

If you use percentages for positioning, it will automatically scale with the browser window size.